# Inductor power choke

Tags: power, power-electronics, inductor, components, identification

I'm looking for this inductor 10 µH.

Need help to recognize series model of this IC's inductor.

[image: Photo of inductor]

Comment: What is ”this ics L”? Could be anything. Why do you need it?

Comment: Looks like a very poorly designed SMPS. National Semi IC, adjustable output, but I can't recognize the IC markings. What is the question about?

Comment: So you know it's 10 µH, then just replace it with a 10 µH. What's the problem?

Comment: Looks like a LM2655 standard switcher.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all. 
its aspi0804t 10uh